# how to toggle display between two different classnames with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, web-frontend

I have four filter buttons (I want only two to show at a time) so I gave the first buttons `.switch1` and the second buttons `.switch2` . Now I have a 'switch filter' button which if the user clicks it should switch `.switch1` `display:block` to `none` and `.switch2` `display:none` to `block` .

```html
<div class="switch2">
   <label>Year</label>
   <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <option selected>2022</option>
      <option value="1">2021</option>
      <option value="2">2020</option>
      <option value="2">2019</option>
      <option value="2">2018</option>
      <option value="2">2017</option>
      <option value="2">2016</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="switch1">
   <label>From:</label>
   <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="month-select col-2">
   <div class="switch2">
      <label>Month</label>
      <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
         <option selected>January</option>
         <option value="1">February</option>
         <option value="2">March</option>
         <option value="2">April</option>
         <option value="2">May</option>
         <option value="2">June</option>
         <option value="2">July</option>
         <option value="2">August</option>
         <option value="2">September</option>
         <option value="2">October</option>
         <option value="2">November</option>
         <option value="2">December</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="switch1">
      <label>To:</label>
      <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="ms-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
   <div class=""><button class="btn-dark px-3 py-1 filterbtn">Filter</button></div>
</div>
```

This is the screenshot of how the first & second buttons look in my site
[first buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vg5K.png)
[second buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eocp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give hidden class to the first set and then toggle that class back and forth

```js
let switchBtn = document.querySelector('button')
let switch1 = document.querySelectorAll('.switch1')
let switch2 = document.querySelectorAll('.switch2')

function switchFilters() {
  let array = [...switch1, ...switch2]
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i].classList.toggle('hidden')
  }
}

switchBtn.onclick = switchFilters
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch2 hidden">
  <label>Year</label>
  <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <option selected>2022</option>
    <option value="1">2021</option>
    <option value="2">2020</option>
    <option value="2">2019</option>
    <option value="2">2018</option>
    <option value="2">2017</option>
    <option value="2">2016</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="switch1">
  <label>From:</label>
  <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
</div>

<div class="month-select col-2">
  <div class="switch2 hidden">
    <label>Month</label>
    <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <option selected>January</option>
      <option value="1">February</option>
      <option value="2">March</option>
      <option value="2">April</option>
      <option value="2">May</option>
      <option value="2">June</option>
      <option value="2">July</option>
      <option value="2">August</option>
      <option value="2">September</option>
      <option value="2">October</option>
      <option value="2">November</option>
      <option value="2">December</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="switch1">
    <label>To:</label>
    <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
  </div>

  <div class="ms-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
    <div class=""><button class="btn-dark px-3 py-1 filterbtn">Filter</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still didnt work. The problem is probably in the way I linked it. I put the js code in a script tag in the html head, just before the title. Is that good?

Comment: What's not working?
@Leon is 'hidden' CSS class with display NONE toggles? Does it applies from the start?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fb = document.querySelector('.filterbtn');
let s1 = document.querySelectorAll('.switch1');
let s2 = document.querySelectorAll('.switch2');

fb.addEventListener('click',function(){
    s1.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.toggle('switch');
    });
    s2.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.toggle('switch');
    });
});
```

```css
.switch{
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="switch2 switch">
   <label>Year</label>
   <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
      <option selected>2022</option>
      <option value="1">2021</option>
      <option value="2">2020</option>
      <option value="2">2019</option>
      <option value="2">2018</option>
      <option value="2">2017</option>
      <option value="2">2016</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="switch1">
   <label>From:</label>
   <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="month-select col-2">
   <div class="switch2 switch">
      <label>Month</label>
      <select class="px-3 py-1 form-select bg-btn" aria-label="Default select example" style="font-size: 14px;">
         <option selected>January</option>
         <option value="1">February</option>
         <option value="2">March</option>
         <option value="2">April</option>
         <option value="2">May</option>
         <option value="2">June</option>
         <option value="2">July</option>
         <option value="2">August</option>
         <option value="2">September</option>
         <option value="2">October</option>
         <option value="2">November</option>
         <option value="2">December</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="switch1">
      <label>To:</label>
      <input class="px-3 py-1 fr-to bg-btn" type="date" name="" id="" style="font-size: 14px;">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="ms-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
   <div class=""><button class="btn-dark px-3 py-1 filterbtn">Filter</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, another tiny problem. It doesnt work on my end, I tried it in my head tag with the script tag and it didnt work

Comment: Did you add the 'switch' class to the divs that meant to be hidden first?

Comment: Try @Smollet777 answer

Comment: It still didnt work. The problem is probably in the way I linked it. I put the js code in a script tag in the html head, just before the title. Is that good? And yes I tried @smollet777 answer too

Comment: add the script just before body's closing tag